# Set up Auto-zone placement in dataproc workflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to set up Auto Zone placement in a Dataproc Workflow Template

I am trying to set up Auto Zone placement in a Dataproc Workflow Template similarly as it is done when [create a cluster](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/auto-zone) without Template Workflow

Google Cloud SDK 244.0.0
Start from a docker image:

```
docker run -ti google/cloud-sdk:slim bash
```

Register in google cloud with service account

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=$GOOGLE_SDK_CREDENTIALS

gcloud config set project $PROJECT

gcloud compute project-info add-metadata \
    --metadata google-compute-default-region=$REGION
```

Create template

```
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates create $TEMPLATE_NAME --project=$PROJECT --region=$REGION

gcloud dataproc workflow-templates set-managed-cluster $TEMPLATE_NAME  \
 --cluster-name $CLUSTER_NAME \
 --project=$PROJECT \
 --region=$REGION
```

Instead auto select a zone, I am asked to choose a zone:

```
For the following cluster:
 - [mycluster]
choose a zone:
 [1] asia-east1-a
 [2] asia-east1-b
 [3] asia-east1-c
 [4] asia-east2-a
 [5] asia-east2-b
 [6] asia-east2-c
 [7] asia-northeast1-a
 ...
 [48] us-central1-c
 [49] us-central1-f
 [50] us-east1-b
Did not print [11] options.
Too many options [61]. Enter "list" at prompt to print choices fully.
Please enter your numeric choice:
```

Is there another way to use Auto Zone using dataproc template workflow

Comment: I reproduced the problem, it looks like a bug of workflow template, it doesn't support `--zone=""`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `--zone=""`? According to the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/auto-zone):

> If you ran the gcloud config set compute/zone command to set a default zone, you must supply the --zone= or zone="" flag to gcloud dataproc clusters create in order to enable the Auto Zone feature.

EDIT: I reproduced the problem, it looks like a bug of workflow template, it doesn't support `--zone=""`.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation, it says:

> ... To create a Cloud Dataproc cluster that uses Auto Zone placement, use the gcloud dataproc clusters create command. Set the --region flag to a non-global region, and omit the --zone flag (or leave the flag empty: --zone= or zone="").
>
> Note: If you ran the gcloud config set compute/zone command to set a default zone, you must supply the --zone= or zone="" flag to gcloud dataproc clusters create in order to enable the Auto Zone feature. Power Shell users must surround the empty quotes with single quotes: --zone='""'. ..."

but it does not work with template workflow.
If I set the region and omit the zone, then ask for the zone later.
If I set the zone and add --zone="" or --zone=, ask for the zone anyway.

Comment: Thanks, we'll look into this

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, you can get it to work by adding the [`--quiet`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--quiet) flag to the `set-managed-cluster` command. This will skip over the zone selection prompt and clusters will be created in different zones (within the region) each time.

For example:

```sh
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates set-managed-cluster $TEMPLATE_NAME  \
--cluster-name $CLUSTER_NAME \
--project=$PROJECT \
--region=$REGION \
--zone="" \
--master-machine-type $MACHINE_TYPE \
--worker-machine-type $MACHINE_TYPE \
--num-workers $NUM_WORKERS \
--quiet
```